# How to ensure a TypeError if the value provided is not of the type implied by another property

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic type that will enforce the type of a given property (`value`) based on the value of another (`field`), where the value of `field` is a key in the type provided as the generic's parameter.

Here is what I have tried:

```
type Rule<M, F extends keyof M = keyof M> = {
    field: F;
    value: M[F];
};
```

Usage:

```
interface MyModel {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    isActive: boolean;
}

const rule1: Rule<MyModel> = {
    field: 'age',
    value: 'twentynine'
    // ^^  string | number | boolean
};
```

Currently, the type of `rule1.value` is a union of all types in `MyModel`, no matter what the value of `rule1.field` is.

Instead, I'm hoping for `rule1.value` to be of type `number` because the value "age" I have provided to `rule1.field` is a key in `MyModel` and the type is `number`.

The following examples would have no errors:

```
const rule2: Rule<MyModel> = {
    field: 'age',
    value: 29
};

const rule3: Rule<MyModel> = {
    field: 'firstName',
    value: 'George'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because the `F` type can't be inferred from the object assignation.

Here is a possible solution to your problem which consists in using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in order to build a union type with every entry of your interface:

```
type Rule<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { field: K, value: T[K] };
}[keyof T];

interface MyModel {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  isActive: boolean;
};

const rule1: Rule<MyModel> = {
  field: 'age',
  value: 'twentynine'
};

const rule2: Rule<MyModel> = {
  field: 'age',
  value: 29
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASgrgGwgHgCoD4oF4oG8BQUUA2gNJQCWAdlANYQgD2AZlKgLoBceUzFECACbdSAGigA3AIYI4EbqjLsoAXwDc+FcXpNWHDfmrAIAJ2ZSAxtACyIa40EC8hXhRMBnYADkpAW3lQnibUAOYaRAhSnj7+3EGh4VBSIQFUcL4ARqaJFO4AghbAFBIBGYyMSFJUGur4+BaMVJ5QJogQAIzc8EjItvaOCJg4BER8AsJQAOTJEJOiLtKyAZPAAO4QVKBU1LOaBg1NwC1tAExdbb12DgJDzqP8QtzTKXMLMnLcJwCce0A)

Comment: Great, thanks. This works, albeit with somewhat confusing error messaging, but I suppose that's classic TS! I wasn't aware we could use square bracket notation to access types in this way. Could you point to any documentation on that?

Comment: Do you mean square brackets other than in the mapped types? I admit that the error message is confusing, it's because the system tries to match every item of the union type, and only the last failed check shows

Comment: Yes, those that follow the Rule type's body `{}`.

Comment: Oh, that's just [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)